# div clickable with padding

Tags: html, hyperlink, padding

I want to make my whole div clickable so I changed the style of the link in the div so it takes the whole size of the div. But when I add padding to the div, the background does expand, but my link doesn't.

Here is what I have :

html :

```
<div id="b_register">
<a href="#"> Register </a>
</div>
```

css :

```
#b_register {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
}


#b_register a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}

#b_register:hover{
    background-color: #009FD6;
}
```

Or you can also go there 
http://jsfiddle.net/EycDQ/1/

What I want is to make the div clickable even with paddings, and without using any Onclick event on the div.

Thank you!

Comment: Does your jsfiddle have to work? because it doesn't here.

Comment: I know, it's not about JS here but HTML/CSS. I changed some name or links from my real code but nothing important.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you move the background color, hover effect and padding to the
>   anchor tag instead of the div element?

Anchors will have just their text be clickable unless they have some sort of background, or use padding to expand the clickable area. Spacer gifs (1px by 1px transparent .gifs) are used for this purpose on items that need to be transparent, if for some reason the div must have the background color/hover effect.

I've modified your fiddle to change just the following:

```
#b_register a {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    #b_register a:hover{
    background-color: #009FD6;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EycDQ/9/

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the `<a>` tag around the `<div>` rather than the other way?

```
<a href="#">
  <div id="b_register">
     Register
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I will give it a try.

Edit :
Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think about this before!

Comment: This is not good. By default a is an inline element and div is a block element. You should not include block elements inside inline elements. This will not pass validation.

Comment: A little update from 2017 - <a> tags wrapping around block elements are totally cool now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add padding to your  tag and adjust the div size.

```
#b_register a {
    padding:10px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EycDQ/7/

Comment: Thank you, I will try this too, seems to be a better way than the answer bellow according to mgamer

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is simple you can simply add event `onclick` to your div then use `window.location = "Your_URL";` to change the location

```
#b_register{cursor: pointer;}

<div id="b_register" onclick="window.location='google.com'">Register</div>
```